# Force Quit Disk Utility to Cancel 7 pass Erase and Now Disk is not usable

Tags: disk-utility, usb

I accidentally performed a 7 pass erase on my usb drive, and I don't want to wait that long time so I forced quit the Disk Utility. However, after doing that I found out that my disk is kind of unusable. I couldn't format it nor could I erase it since it would give me the error

```
Error: -69888: Couldn't unmount disk
```

Below is the information of my usb drive right now, what should I do to make this usb usable again?[image]

Comment: Did you try unplugging your USB and plugging it in again?  Or rebooting your system?  If not try that. Either will do but rebooting is probably safer. Then run `diskutil list` from terminal and edit results into your question if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I have tried all of that, and it didn't work. I can see the drive in disk utility. and I have tried ```diskutil eraseVolume disk2 ``` and ```diskutil fdisk -iy disk2``` and nothing works. I can neither mount it nor erase it since it wouldn't unmount

Comment: Your picture is `disk2s2` (the partition) not `disk2` (the physical disk).  You could try something like `diskutil eraseVolume JHFS+ WhateverName disk2s2` (or `/Volumes/disk2s2` but **not** `disk2`). Please add results of `diskutil list` to be sure.

Comment: OMG that worked! Thank you BTW what does JHFS+ mean? Also the name is because after I force quit the disk utility, the name of the entire drive just changed to disk2s2. I thought it is just a name that stands for the physical disk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You needed to recreate a filesystem. You tried `diskutil eraseVolume disk2` but this is invalid. See [man diskutil](https://ss64.com/osx/diskutil.html) or `diskutil eraseVolume --help` for details.

Firstly you need to tell *diskutil* what filesystem (if any) to use and secondly while in some odd cases (RAID for example) you create a filesystem on the whole physical disk normally it is on the partition. From your picture `disk2` is the physical disk and `disk2s2` is the partition so you want something like this:

`diskutil eraseVolume JHFS+ WhateverName disk2s2` where :

- `JHFS+` is the filesystem you want (in this case journalled HFS+).  Valid values can be seen by entering `diskutil listFilesystems` but from your picture it seems you had a HFS filesystem before.
- `WhateverName` is the volume name you want (can be any valid characters, quoted if necessary)
- `disk2s2` is the **partition** you want to create the filesystem on.

---

## What probably happened

From your picture `disk2` is your physical USB drive.  When you format a drive in *Disk Utility* macOS creates a small file called a *partition table* at the start (and if a GPT disk the end) of the disk.  This file holds information showing where partitions are on the disk and their type.  It will then normally create a small (invisible) 200MiB EFI partition (`disk2s1`) followed by one or more other partitions (`disk2s2`, `disk2s3` etc) that you request.

In your case the second partition was a 256GB HFS partition.  This was probably *journalled* HFS as it is the default, but not necessarily - the filesystem type code `AF00` doesn't distinguish journalling.  You can see from this [support doc](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496) Apple recommends it in many cases.

When you started writing zeros to `disk2s2` it destroyed the filesystem by overwriting it with zeros.  The partition table entry showing the start, end and type (`AF00`) remained.  Therefore creating a filesystem in the partition fixed it.

---

## Note on cleaning

Overwriting 7 times with zeros is a massive overkill.  Once is enough and more than that is a waste of time.

See this stackoverflow question: [How does a 7- or 35-pass erase work? Why would one use these methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276832/how-does-a-7-or-35-pass-erase-work-why-would-one-use-these-methods)

or this askubuntu question: [Possibility of recovering files from a dd zero-filled hard disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21501/possibility-of-recovering-files-from-a-dd-zero-filled-hard-disk)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue myself. In the tickets I read, they all resulted in someone saying to force quit and the hardware being damaged.
The resource lx07 referenced, [man diskutil](https://ss64.com/osx/diskutil.html), was very useful, particularly  in troubleshooting the damaged hardware. The most effective solution I found was `diskutil zeroDisk [device]` (note that devices with a space in the name require `\` to be placed before the space, to be recognized), which– unlike the Disk Utility GUI– shows the progress toward completion in a percentage with a simulated spinning motion (cycling `– \ | /` pattern) to indicate activity, as well as an estimated time remaining.